# How to convert date string to date in Excel MMM-dd-yyyy (eg: APR-01-2010)

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet which contains more than 10000 records. In that dates are stored as string. Format is MMM-dd-yyyy (eg: APR-01-2010). How to convert to actual dates in Ms Excel

Comment: The date format here is quite different from the one in the question that this is marked a duplicate of (month strings vs just numbers especially) (And output format is Excel data vs Unix time in other question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
=0+(MID(A1,5,3)&REPLACE(A1,4,3,))
```

Regards

Comment: Alternatively: Use the Text to Columns functionality. In Step 3, select 'Date' and in the dropdown 'MDY'

Comment: Yes. Much better idea.

Comment: Thank you XOR LX. Its works

Comment: Sure, though I'd strongly recommend the solution as given by Philippe K over mine. Much more efficient.